# OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid Argument with Pickle

Tags: python, pickle

I wrote a small program that pickles a little dictionary to a file every hour, once on startup. I was using pickle.dump, and I originally did it on my macbook laptop. On there, I designated the filename I wanted, and the program just created the file to dump the data into.
However, the exact same code is done on my PC, and I got the titled error. I thought it was because pathing is different on PC, so I tried doing "C:/..../playerdata/filename" instead of just "./playerdata/filename" but to no avail.

This is the block of code:

```py
def write_data(self,master_table,label,num):
  filename = './playerdata/'+str(master_table["num"])+' - '+label+' - data'
  with open(filename,"wb") as file:
    pickle.dump(master_table,file,protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
  #masterlist[num] = [filename,label] #doesn't really matter for the problem
```

I'm assuming the error is coming about because there is no file called that, but when I ran it on my mac it just created it. I believe pickle does that, but the code never gets the chance to dump it because it needs to be opened first.

Am I missing some kind of formatting? How do I get the file to be created without error?

Comment: Certain things are not allowed in filenames on Windows. What's the final filename you're trying to write to? (If you e.g. `print(filename)`?)

Comment: @AKX something like "0-Hour 0/00/00.067415 - data" Is there something not allowed there?

Comment: Yes. Slashes not allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your filename can contain slashes (which separate directories as you know), you'll need to make sure the intermediate directories exist too. That's easy enough to do in one fell swoop with `os.makedirs()`.

For brevity's sake, I also changed this to use f-strings (Python 3.6+) for the filename generation.

```
def write_data(self, master_table, label, num):
    filename = f'./playerdata/{master_table["num"]} - {label} - data'
    os.makedirs(os.dirname(filename), exist_ok=True)  # <- New
    with open(filename, "wb") as file:
        pickle.dump(master_table, file, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```